# Don't succeed to execute .exe using powershell

Tags: powershell

I've looked into the forum for one hour now, and tried everything I've found here but still I don't manage to run my .exe using a powershell script.
Please forgive my ignorance, I'm very new with powershell..

Basically, my script is aimed to daily monitor files loaded.
For this, I need to list .txt files in my working directory, which I managed to do.
My issue is that when files arrive in my working folder, they have nonspeaking names that I can't figure out which business it's related to.
There is a RemaneFile1.exe executable that renames files according to some data codes inside my .txt files from something like "Inf320638.txt" to something like "lot_RUHPEG_296_320638" and that is exactly what .exe I would like to run using powershell (I didn't coded it, and I don't know how it works, just that when I manually run it it renames my files just fine).

I've tried those two command lines below, but when I look at my files, they are actually not renamed.
1. `&".\INFOCENTRE\LOTS\RenameFile1.exe`
=> When I check my file name it's still like "Inf320638.txt".
2. `Start-Process ".\INFOCENTRE\LOTS\RenameFile1.exe"` => A command prompt shows up for an instant, but when I check my file name it's like "Inf320638.txt".

Any help would be highly appreciated,

Brgs,
Thomas.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to run the executable with the following arguments:

```
Start-Process .\INFOCENTRE\LOTS\RenameFile1.exe -WorkingDirectory .\INFOCENTRE\LOTS -Wait
```

It might be, that the workingdirectory is what screws it up. The `-wait` switch lets powershell wait for the programm to finish, you could omit it.

Comment: Hi,
Thank you for the reply, indeed it's able to run it that way.
However, do you any other argument to specify so it won't popup a security warning? (you know the popup you have to click run to confirm..)
As I plan to schedule the execution of my powershell then, I don't want to have to manually confirm.

Comment: Fixed, I wasn't actually working with .\... but full server path (like if it was remote) that's why it was warning for security.
As I actually plan to locally run both my ps script and .exe I can work with .\...

Comment: Didn't know about the diffenrence in realtive and absolute path either, thanks for sharing.